# github, SHA-1 hash and git duplicates

Tags: github, duplicates, git-diff, sha1

I have a github repo which seems to have duplicate commits. Each commit has the same message string and the same date/author, but different SHA-1 hash sums. For example, in my log I found the following quadruple:

```
 'commit 55e55517bf32b7ba7382b97f41a1514af8a5f5dc',
 'Author: dermen <dermen@stanford.edu>',
 'Date:   Tue Feb 19 20:03:35 2013 -0800',
 'finished with the cromermann edition',
 'commit 814fb08e0d42588a500947cba42a980ac24c01b8',
 'Author: dermen <dermen@stanford.edu>',
 'Date:   Tue Feb 19 20:03:35 2013 -0800',
 'finished with the cromermann edition',
 'commit a5f581f513d12e95627669f61cfe27064ffe8319',
 'Author: dermen <dermen@stanford.edu>',
 'Date:   Tue Feb 19 20:03:35 2013 -0800',
 'finished with the cromermann edition',
 'commit a264614b674e1ad2c4c8cc953cb27cf77c0d2615',
 'Author: dermen <dermen@stanford.edu>',
 'Date:   Tue Feb 19 20:03:35 2013 -0800',
 'finished with the cromermann edition',
```

Everything is identical except for the SHA-1 hash. When I run for example

```
git diff 55e55517bf32b7ba7382b97f41a1514af8a5f5dc    814fb08e0d42588a500947cba42a980ac24c01b8
```

I get zero output - doesnt this mean the commits are identical. If this is true, then why would they have separate SHA-1 hash sums  ? Maybe I mis-understand, but shouldn't an SHA-1 hash directly represent content in a file? Hence if the commits are equal then they should have the same hash.

In any case, I am wondering if it is wise / unwise to attempt to filter such apparent duplicates... Any tip/redirection will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A git commit sha is generated from the following information

- commit message
- author signature (identity + timestamp)
- committer signature (identity + timestamp)
- tree sha (hierarchy of directories and files witin the commit)
- list of the shas of the parent commits

As the shas are different, this is because at least one of these information differ.

In order to get a better understanding of what are those data for each commit (and *how* they differ one from another) you can run the following command to get the raw output of each commit

```
$ git show --format=raw <commit_sha>
```

---

### Example of the output of this command

*Based on a random commit of the **[libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2)** project*

```
$ git show --format=raw eb58e2d
commit eb58e2d0be4e07c2ef873a5f0562eaa90826c2de
tree 41959050b1e3adb428e140102a0c321949be516b
parent 3b5001b4c911db9c47d62399c1adc03bd8a3ca72
parent 3e9e6cdaff8acb11399736abbf793bf2d000d037
author Vicent Marti <tanoku@gmail.com> 1371063948 +0200
committer Vicent Marti <tanoku@gmail.com> 1371063948 +0200

    Merge remote-tracking branch 'arrbee/minor-paranoia' into development

diff --cc src/refdb.c
index 359842e,4271b58..6da409a
--- a/src/refdb.c
+++ b/src/refdb.c
@@@ -86,9 -86,10 +86,10 @@@ int git_refdb_compress(git_refdb *db
        return 0;
  }

 -static void refdb_free(git_refdb *db)
 +void git_refdb__free(git_refdb *db)
  {
        refdb_free_backend(db);
+       git__memset(db, 0, sizeof(*db));
        git__free(db);
  }
```

---

### Back to your questions

> I get zero output - doesn't this mean the commits are identical

This means that the content of what is being pointed at by the commits is the same. But the metadata may certainly differ.

> Maybe I mis-understand, but shouldn't an SHA-1 hash directly represent content in a file?

In Git, SHA-1 hashes are used to represent git objects: **blobs** (i.e. files), **trees** (i.e. list of blobs and sub trees) and **commits**. You can find more information about this in the chapter **[9.2 Git Internals - Git Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)** of the **Pro Git** book.

> For example, in my log I found the following quadruple

This may happen when you amend/rebase/fixup the content of your commits for instance. In these cases, only the commit date would change.

> In any case, I am wondering if it is wise / unwise to attempt to filter such apparent duplicates

You don't have to cleanup by yourself. Those objects are stored in the Git object database. Git implements a garbage collecting mechanism which will regularly and automatically remove orphaned objects from it (see **[git-gc documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)** for more details).

Comment: thanks, I ran the command you posted, and discovered that the only difference between the 4 posted commit-copies (the quadruple listed above) is the parent ( they each have a unique parent, which gives them each a unique sha ).   Any ideas on cleaning this up ? Is it even necessary to do so ?

Comment: *Any ideas on cleaning this up ? Is it even necessary to do so ?* -> See the last part of the answer. There's no need to cleanup. Those "dangling" commits will be automatically removed after some time. If you're *really* willing to do this, then `git gc` is your friend. :-) In order to get a grasp of the command, make sure to firstly perform this on a backup of your repo.